# Find all $A$ such that $f(x) = \sum_{n \in A} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ is bounded for $x<0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, power-series

> Let  $\mathbb{R}_- = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \leq 0 \}$, $\mathbb{N} = \{0,1, 2, ...\}$. Find all subsets $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ such that the function $f : \mathbb{R}_- \to \mathbb{R}$,$$f(x) := \sum_{n \in A} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
> is bounded.

Note that the function $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}_-$ and not all of $\mathbb{R}$. Moreover $f$ looks like a lot $x \mapsto e^x$. So one set for which $f$ is bounded is $A = \mathbb{N}$, as well as $A=\{0\}$.

Moreover we need to find an equilibrium in $A$ in the following sense: if there are too many even numbers $f$ will not be bounded, and if there are too many odd numbers $f$ also can't be bounded. So I think there is a $K \in \mathbb{R}$ such that if we want $f$ to be bounded then the number of even numbers in $A$ is at most $K \times$ the number of odd numbers in $A$.

Thank you.

Comment: What is $\Bbb {R}_ -$?

Comment: $\{ a \in \mathbb R : a < 0\}$

Comment: $\mathbb N, \{0\}, \mathbb N \setminus \{0\},\varnothing$.  These four.  Any others?

Comment: I'm not sure what the answer is, but don't $A=k\mathbb{N}$ where $k$ is odd not also work?

Comment: @Keen-amateur let's try $A=3\mathbb{N}$. You get $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{x^{3n}}{(3n)!} = \dfrac{1}{3}\left(e^x+2e^{-x}\cos\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right)\right)$$ which does not converge as $x \to -\infty$.

Comment: Vaguely related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3728903

Comment: I think that only subsets like $A_n=\{k\in\mathbb{N}:k\ge n\}$ can be proved to give $f(x)$ bounded at $-\infty$.

Comment: ^ $A_2 = \{k \in \mathbb{N} : k \ge 2\}$ yields $f(x) = e^x-1-x$ which is not bounded as $x \to -\infty$. Similarly, $A_n$ for $n \ge 2$ doesn't work.

Comment: What about finite set $A$?

Comment: @W.Wongcharoenbhorn polynomials aren't bounded over $\mathbb{R}_-$.